# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

Tags: angular, typescript

I am storing the title and the lastname in the token. After decoding the token i am unable to get the title and the lastname to display it on login. Its giving me error "cannot read property title of  null".
Anyone enter code herecan help me in this regard.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import * as jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { tokenGetter } from '../app.module';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-home',
  templateUrl: './admin-home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-home.component.css']
})
export class AdminHomeComponent implements OnInit {
  token: any;

  title = this.getDecodedAccessToken(this.token).title;
  lastname = this.getDecodedAccessToken(this.token).lastname;
  // title = 'Herr';
  // lastname = 'Fioretto';
  constructor(
    private router : Router,
    private authService: AuthService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  //Decoding token
  getDecodedAccessToken(token: string): any {
    console.log('in decode token function');
    try{
      let decodedToken = jwt_decode(token);
        console.log(decodedToken);
        return decodedToken;
      }
    catch(Error){
        return null;
    }
  }



  logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.router.navigate(['./login']);
  }

  isLoggedIn()
  {
    console.log('in isloggedIn Function')
    if(this.authService.isAuthenticated())
      {
        this.router.navigate(['./admin-home']);
      }
    else
      {
        this.router.navigate(['./login']);
      }

  }


}
```

Comment: `this.getDecodedAccessToken(this.token)` returns `null`

Comment: oky so how can i fix this do i need to write a separate function?

Comment: I also tried it with a get title() function and there was same error

Comment: Check what you're giving to the method and what it returns - if there are any errors, it would be there and you should know your data and expectations better than we do.

Comment: Alright Thanks i wil check iit put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try this make it empty string and this won't change the style

```
title: string = '';
lastname: string = '';
ngOnInit() {
  this.title = this.getDecodedAccessToken(this.token).title;
  this.lastname = this.getDecodedAccessToken(this.token).lastname;
}
```

Comment: Cannot find name 'title'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.title'. Also for lastname and yeah this is also changing the style

Comment: i have updated the code (this.title and this.lastname)

Comment: it damges the whole layout of the page

Comment: why not you simply set value and get it from localStorage? like localStorage.set('title', title); or localStorage.set('lastname', lastname); then get it anywhere localStorage.getItem('title');

Comment: title = this.userService.getDecodedAccessToken(localStorage.getItem('token')).title;
  lastname = this.userService.getDecodedAccessToken(localStorage.getItem('token')).lastname   WOKRED::::

Comment: Good To hear that, then tick mark this as an answer so it can help others

Answer (score 0):

It's better to call you methods inside ngOnInit.

```
title: string;
lastname: string;
ngOnInit() {
  title = this.getDecodedAccessToken(this.token).title;
  lastname = this.getDecodedAccessToken(this.token).lastname;
}
```

Comment: DIDNT WORKED it changed the whole style of the page